# Why updating DateTime in MongoDB getting wrong value?

Tags: mongodb, datetime, nosql

I have one model with DateUpdated DateTime property.

Before i update that model, my model information's are

[image: before changes]

After i update my model information's are

[image: after changes]

Why MongoDB store wrong DateUpdated value? I tried several times with debugger, and looks like every time that value is changed but with wrong DateTime.

Im using C# Driver.

My Update function is

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id", p.UserID);
var update = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.Replace(p);
SafeModeResult success =  MongoRepository.Profiles().Update(query, update);
```

SafeModeResult is always success.

My DateUpdated Bson property is

```
[BsonElement("da")]
[BsonDateTimeOptions(Representation = BsonType.Document)]
public DateTime DateUpdated{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB stores DateTime values in UTC. What you are seeing is the conversion of local time to UTC.

The best way to handle timezones is to keep all your data in UTC (including in your data model, not just the database) and only convert to local time at the point you display a value to the user.